# Node.js How to import and export modules with sub functions

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am writing an application and ran into a bit of trouble. I setup a "class" in JavaScript and within that class I call multiple this.demo = function(){}. When i export the module and then import on another page, then attempt to use one of the sub functions, my application tells me it does not recognize the function. Here is an example.. how should i be doing this?

```
function demo(){ this.test = function(msg){console.log(msg);} }
module.exports.demo = demo;
```

Then inside of another class I import the demo.js file

```
function newClass(){
   this.demo = require('./demo');
   this.demo.test('Hello');
}
```

The editor tells me that it does not recognize test...

Comment: `require('./demo')` returns the `module.exports` object from `demo.js`. You gave it one property, called `demo`, which is a constructor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an export error in your code.

```
function demo(){ this.test = function(msg){console.log(msg);} }
module.exports.test = demo;
```

Now you can call it correctly:

```
function newClass(){

   this.demo = require('./demo');
   this.demo.test('Hello');

   // If you're still confused, use the console.log!
   console.log(this.demo);

}
```

The output of the `console.log(this.demo)` will show the structure or your demo file.

**Edit:** To get a function as result of the `require` call, export like this:

```
module.exports = function demo(){ this.test = function(msg){console.log(msg);} }
```

Now you call directly:

```
function newClass(){

   this.demo = require('./demo');
   this.demo.test('Hello');

}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly. To rephrase my question, can i call this.demo.test or can I only call this.demo?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example where the function itself is exported as the root of the module. Hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: What you posted sends the string to the function demo, but there is no output because that never reaches the this.test function. From what you noticed.. I cannot use the same export name as the function i am exporting. What you failed to explain is that once i have the export correct, i can make calls to the sub functions using this.demo.test("Hello").